# .asmx file requires rebuild before allowing full site build to succeed

Tags: web-services, asmx, vs-web-site-project, rebuild

I've been working with my web application for a long time, and recently two of the asmx files have started behaving rather oddly.  As far as I know, nobody has touched them in ages, but suddenly when I go to build the website it fails because custom classes being called in the asmx file aren't recognized, when all the other pages that use them are fine.

The weird thing is, if I individually click on the asmx file and select "Rebuild Page" for both of them, everything works fine until the next time I try to build the website.

Does anyone know what I can do to fix this issue?  It's become a rather large annoyance, though I'm still able to work around it.  Anything is helpful, even if it's just steps to follow to troubleshoot.

An example of some of the errors I get is:

Type expected
Type "Class.Subclass" is undefined

Comment: What kind of project is this? Web site or Web Application Project? I strongly recommend against using "web site" for reasons just like this: weird stuff.

Comment: Yeah, it's a web site.  I used to code in php so I picked it thinking it would be simpler, but like you say, I'm running into a few very odd things like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured it out :)  It seems like the problem had to do with a class both of the .asmx files were using.  I opened up the class, right clicked and used the Visual Studio "Rename" feature to give it (and all usages of it) a different name and the error no longer occurs.